# Malloc error when working with BigInteger arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, bigint

I'm using [Matt McCutchen's BigInteger library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) for a project of mine and I'm having a little problem when working with BigInteger arrays:

The following code is giving me `malloc: *** error for object 0x7: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

```
long create_db(BigInteger min_abc, BigInteger max_abc,
    BigInteger*& abc_range, stats*& run_stats) {

    // Easiest way to do ceil with bigint is via an if statement
    BigInteger temp = (max_abc - min_abc) % JUMP == 0 ? (max_abc - min_abc) / JUMP : ((max_abc - min_abc) / JUMP) + 1;
    long num;
    sscanf(bigIntegerToString(temp).c_str(), "%ld", &num);
    // If the number is too big for a long, it cannot be addressed by a 64-bit computer.


    abc_range = (BigInteger*) malloc(num * sizeof(BigInteger));
    run_stats = (stats*) malloc(num * sizeof(stats));

    // Min is already known, so it is unnecessary
    for(long i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if (i == num) {
            abc_range[i - 1] = max_abc;
        } else {
            BigInteger temp = min_abc + (JUMP * i);
            abc_range[i - 1] = temp; // <--- Error here
        }
        //abc_range[i - 1] = i == num ? max_abc : min_abc + JUMP * i;
        run_stats[i - 1] = READY;
    }

    return num;
}
```

The address 0x7 is the array pointed to by abc_range[0]:

```
p abc_range[0]
(BigInteger) $1 = {
  sign = positive
  mag = {
    NumberlikeArray<unsigned long> = {
      cap = 0
      len = 1
      blk = 0x0000000000000007
    }
  }
}
```

and for some reason my program is trying to free the pointer when using the operator `=`. I've tried using `new` instead of `malloc` but I get the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you doing using `malloc()` in a C++ project?  You might note that the `scanf()` family of functions give no promises about what will happen if you try to convert a number that's too big.  If you use `strtol()` or one of its relatives, the behaviour is defined.  If you use `sscanf()`, even if you test the return value (which apparently you don't), you can't tell about overflows etc.

Comment: Lots of the code I am using is C code ported do C++. It should work in theory.

Comment: Yes, it works.  It isn't really C++, though.  Well, it's a sort of C++, but usually not the best choice.

Comment: Since I am using the result of that operation to address an array, I really don't care for numbers that won't fit in a long, since it wouldn't work anyways.

Comment: I'm not convinced we've got enough code to repro the problem.  What's the type of `blk`?  If it is meant to be a pointer to allocated memory, you've got a duff address (a NULL pointer plus 7 bytes offset).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler blk is something internal to BigInteger. All the code that I wrote myself is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc` allocates memory but doesn't call any constructor. That's why `new` has been introduced in C++.

You should try with

```
abc_range = new BigInteger[num];
```

or you must explicily call the constructor with a placement new after `malloc`.

The default constructor of `NumberLikeArray` is the following

```
NumberlikeArray() : cap(0), len(0) {
        blk = NULL;
    }
```

This means that the default constructor is definitely not called, since you've got 0x7 in there.

Comment: "I've tried using `new` instead of `malloc` but I get the same result."

Comment: Which `new` did you try?

Comment: `abc_range = new BigInteger[num];`. I tried it again and for some reason it worked. I might not have saved the file last time.

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho - The reason it worked, "for some reason", is because this is the right thing to do. Using `malloc` in C++ code almost always is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: It didn't work the first time. I don't know why. I did try using `new` before I asked.